# Kafka Connect - Missing Text

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka Version : 2.12-2.1.1

I created a very simple example to create a source and sink connector by using following commands :

```
bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat config\connect-standalone.properties config\connect-file-source.properties config\connect-file-sink.properties
```

Source file name : text_2.txt

Sink file name : test.sink_2.txt

A topic named "**connect-test-2**" is used and I created a consumer in PowerShell to show the result.

It works perfect at the first time. However, after i reboot my machine and start everything again. I found that some text are missing.

For example, when I type the characters below into test_2.txt file and save as following:

```
HAHAHA..

missing again
some text are missing

I am able to enter text
first letter is missing

testing testing.
```

The result windows (Consumer) and the sink file shows the following:

[image: Value shows in consumer]

[image: Value shows in Sink File]

As you can see, some text are missing and i cannot find out why this happen. Any advice?

[Added information below]

**connect-file-source.properties**

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=test_2.txt
topic=connect-test-2
```

**connect-file-sink.properties**

```
name=local-file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=test.sink_2.txt
topics=connect-test-2
```

Comment: can you amend your question to include your `config\connect-file-source.properties` and `config\connect-file-sink.properties`

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt. I included the setting into my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *strange behaviour* is caused be the way you are modifying the sink file (`text_2.txt`).

How you applied changes after stoping the connector:

- Using some editor <-- **I think you use that method**
- Append only new characters to the end of file

`FileStreamSource` track changes based on the position in the file. You are using Kafka Connect in standalone mode so current position is written in `/tmp/connect.offsets` file.

If you modify source file using the editor, the whole content of the file has been changed. However `FileStreamSource` checks only if the size has change and poll characters, which offsets in the file is bigger then last processed by the Connector.

You should modify source file only by appending new characters to the end of the file

Comment: Thanks @wardziniak. I opened the test_2.txt file in notepad++ and keep "appending" new characters at the end of the file then press ctrl+c. And, I just tried to append more characters and the behavior is same...

Comment: @BennyChan, Instead notepad++ use some command line tool. I'm not an expert in PowerShell. In Unix it would be some like: `echo "hello" > test_2.txt`, For PowerShell I've found following command: `Add-Content test_2.txt "Test"` (https://www.tachytelic.net/2018/11/how-to-append-text-to-a-file-with-windows-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks @wardziniak. I followed your suggestion to create a .bat file to write lines into the file and it works without issue. I have also tried to create a simple nodejs script to insert to rows and not problem either. I think the problem is happened when the text file is being updated manually by some application (notepad ++ or even note pad)? But why?! Although i cannot think of any user case to use connector to connect a text file being updated via notepad or text editor, I think this must be able to handled, am i right?

Comment: @BennyChan, I think the issue is with the way, that some application (notepad ++, etc) update file. They should only append at the end of the file, but they rather modify content _inside the file_. As examples shows, when characters are only appended (PowerShell scripts) it works properly